# how to display div over another div after click of the other div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Weird Title..
anyways
this is my problem I want to display the  `<div id="detail">data</div>` after i click the `<div class="eventName">data</div>`

and here is my jquery code:

```
$(".eventName").click(
        function () {
            var eventId = $(this).attr('id');
            var role    = $(this).attr('dir');
            var todo = 'viewDetails';
            $("#details").load("plugins/company_calendar/calendar.php?eventId="+ eventId +"&todo="+ todo +"&role="+ role );
        }
    );
```

I don't know what to do to display the div#details over the other div..
Can you help me solving this problem??
thanks..

Comment: So you want to new div to overlap the `eventName` div? Like a popup or something?

Comment: yes..something like a pop up or tool tip.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery UI dialog then? http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Comment: i think it would not look good for my site.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sourceContents = $(sourcedivid).html();
$(destinationdivid).html(sourceContents);
```

Copies the contents of sourcedivid to destinationdivid

Beware of memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure the div that you want to display exists in the page and the

```
$("#details").hide();
```

is called when the page loads.

If it dose not exist then you have to create one then append it to the page and the apply the effect.

Comment: why i should need to hide it??
I want to display it over the other div like a pop up.

Comment: This is because you don't want it to be displayed before clicking on the other div. So you have to hide it before user clicks on the div.